# EGLFS and rotation of QT5 application under Linux

Tags: linux, qt, rotation, eglfs

On behalf of my colleague I'd like to ask if it is possible to rotate the whole QT5 (QT 5.6.1-1) application window. We are using EGLFS as a backend on Sitara TI AM335X platform running Linux framebuffer.

The current situation is like this: we have some application which normally is rotated 90 degrees from end user point of view. As a temporary solution my colleague (the developer of this application) is rotating every element in this window to achieve proper visual effect. Unfortunately this rotation takes a lot of time of CPU.

My question is - is it possible to turn the whole window clockwise? I mean is it possible to do it on EGLFS or QT5 level without rotating every single element in the window?

I tried to exchange x-y dimensions (800x480) of the screen but without success. I have also taken a look into a linux kernel driver sources and I see no possibility to rotate the whole screen. I was thinking about creating some another buffer in memory from which I could copy data with rotation to target memory, but I'm not sure if it is good idea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `QT_QPA_EGLFS_ROTATION` environment variable to `90` or `-90`. See [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#eglfs).

Comment: Are you sure that this env variable is working on qt-5.6.1-1?

Comment: No, I'm not. Look into the sources to see if it appears anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation on EGLFS platform was afflicted by a bug [QTBUG-39959](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39959) until version 5.7.x and so the rotation variable was ignored.

The bug is fixed from version 5.8.